# "uitsluitend", logic of its double meaning

Tags: meaning, dutch

First question here.
I found the word "uitsluitend" in Dutch language, and I was explained that it has two meanings, one is the present participle of uitsluiten (~excluding), and the other is an adjective, which means ~exclusive. Now, I would like to know, first, if this is exactly like this, and second, why the adjective has the opposite meaning than the participle, and if there other words with this feature.

---

Edit:

The text that made me question this has a table that reads

> Paar
>
> Paar, uitsluitend minderj. kinderen
>
> Paar, minderj. en meerderj. kinderen
>
> Paar, uitsluitend meeerderj. kinderen

so, as I was told, the second line for example, is all the couples that have minor children; this is why I say that the meaning is opposite, since to say "excluding" and "exclusively" here gives the opposite set of people.

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly as you say. "uitsluitend" is the present participle of uitsluiten, which means to exclude. Also it's an adjective meaning "exclusive". I am sure you could find exactly this information in any dictionary.

I couldn't quite work out why you believe these meanings are opposite though. Obviously if you exclude something/someone, you are being exclusive. The meaning is identical.

Comment: I edited the answer to provide more detail and the example that I am trying to understand